# implement different variables in while loop PHP

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

Lets say for example, I have a form, and i post the values to the next page via an array. 
I would like to create a while loop that would print out the variables individually. 
this is my problem.
 I really have an XML document. This XML document I want it to change variables. So I am assuming that implementing the values i pass via an array from the form would need help from some sort of loop so im guessing the while loop will help because i need to stop the loop.

So I have a hotel form. if there are two rooms, I would like to make the while loop stop at two and insert the values from the array form post. 
I know how to set up a while loop just need some kind guidance to insert the different values into the xml document.

Here is example: 
* There are two rooms i want label 0 and label 1 to go into the child attribute tag, and child 2 and child 3 to go to the 2nd loop within the child attribute tag.

```
$label[0];
$label[1];
$label[2];
$label[3];
$NumberOfRooms = $_POST['NumbersOfRooms']; 
$count = '0';

while ($count > $NumberOfRooms){ //Assuming that there is two rooms 
$xml = '<checkIn>2012-10-15 </checkIn>
<checkOut>2012-10-18</checkOut>
<numberOfAdults>1</NumberOfAdults>
<numberOfChilderen>2</NumberOfChilderen>
  <ChildAges>
  <childAge age ='."3".' /> $label[0]; 
  <childAge age ='."3".' /> $label[1]
  </ChildAges>';
$count++;
}
```

Comment: This question would make more sense with associated (valid and hopefully working) example code ..

Comment: I am sorry, I edit the file to show you what i am trying to say. If you need more example please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code should do the trick for you.

```
<?php
    $label[0];
    $label[1];
    $label[2];
    $label[3];
    $NumberOfRooms = $_POST['NumbersOfRooms']; 
    $xml="";

    for($count=0; $count<$NumberOfRooms; $count++)
    {
    $xml .= '<checkIn>2012-10-15 </checkIn>
    <checkOut>2012-10-18</checkOut>
    <numberOfAdults>1</NumberOfAdults>
    <numberOfChilderen>2</NumberOfChilderen>
      <ChildAges>
      <childAge age ='.$label[floor($count*2))].' />  
      <childAge age ='.$label[floor($count*2)+1].' />
      </ChildAges>';
    }
?>
```

The errors that I saw in your code were as follows:

- Your `$count` was defined as a string. You were comparing it to a number.
- Secondly, assuming `$count` started at zero, how was it ever going to be larger than the number of rooms? I think you got your `<` and `>` muddled up.
- You were overwriting the `$xml` variable each time you looped through your while statement.
- Lastly, it is just my opinion, but if you know you only want to loop through a certain number of times, use a `for` loop over a `while` - there is less chance of muddling up the logic/drop out conditions.

Comment: Should not this text `$label[floor($count/2)]` be `$label[$count].'` ? Because `$label[floor0]` , `$label[floor1]` etc is not defined anywhere, whereas `$label[0]` & `$label[0]` is. Also, `$count/2` & `($count/2)+1` is (when $count = 0, which it will be always, because it is defined in `for loop`)basically `0` & `1`.

Comment: i tried just now and it actually printed 0 and 1 twice, and not 0 1, there after 2 and 3 for both scnarios

Comment: @Davinder Ummm, I am using the `floor` function to round the result down, not referring to a key that doesn't exist. Secondly, he wanted to use `$label[0]` & `$label[1]` in the first loop, and `$label[2]` & `$label[3]` in the second loop. Hence the `floor($count/2)` and `floor($count/2)+1`.

Comment: I got the idea now. Thanks for your time, There's only so much I can learn. And I thank you.